# Moving Smoke as with a train

Tags: smoke-simulation

[image]Trying to get smoke to move or travel as if it was on a old time train running down the tracks. No issues with getting the smoke to work, but can't get it to follow the train as it moves.

Comment: can you show pictures or a gif of the current behavior?

Comment: The circle above the "Train" is the flow. The domain just sits there. I've tried using locations tags in Key frames, but the domain just stays there.

Comment: you could have parented the domain to the smoke object and parented the smoke object to the train. (use ctrl + p to parent)

Comment: also check this Q https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168032/how-do-we-produce-less-smoke